# Convert a 0 V / 3.3 V trigger signal into a 0 V / 5V trigger signal (TTL)

Tags: voltage, driver, ttl, trigger

I have a device sending a square trigger signal 0V / 3.3V, with a BNC connector.
(We usually call it a TTL signal, I don't know if it's the common name? is it relative to Transistor-Transitor-Logic?)

The problem is that the device receiving the signal expects a 0V / 5V trigger, BNC connector.
By looking at the specifications, a high state of 3.3V is not enough.

**Question:** Is there an off-the-self electronic solution to convert a 0 / 3.3 trigger into a 0 / 5 trigger signal ?

Or do I have to solder a small device (powered ?), based on ULN2003 or similar ?

Edit thanks to comments: below is the TTL standard; it seems that my Rx and/or Tx device don't really support it:

[image]

Comment: Basj - Hi, (a) Can you add the *exact* specifications of both sender & receiver, if you have any more info? (b) You mentioned TTL in one place & also said: "*a high state of 3.3V is not enough*" - but that's not true for TTL. See page 4 in [this PDF from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sdyu001ab/sdyu001ab.pdf) showing that for 5V TTL & 3.3V LVTTL levels, the input threshold (Vih) is 2.0 V. Are you *sure* that you really have a problem? :) Can you open the equipment to identify the actual driver & receiver circuits?

Comment: It is true, if the input is truly a TTL logic chip operating at 5 volts then the on voltage is somewhere around 2 Volts ([see here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/logic-signal-voltage-levels/)) as pointed out by @SamGibson. If it doesn't work then the input logic may be made from a different type of technology.

Comment: @SamGibson We use the term "TTL" as a synonym of trigger signal, but we probably use the wrong wording. Is "TTL" a term that is about a specific voltage? BTW does TTL mean "Transistor Transistor Logic"? What is the "official" meaning of TTL in the context of a trigger signal?

Comment: @SamGibson Yes we have a problem. Without a converter to 5V, it doesn't work. Someone did a converter that converts to 5V, then it works, but I'd like to avoid this converter which is not reliable, I would prefer off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: @Basj - Hi, "*Is "TTL" a term that is about a specific voltage?*" Yes, it means (a) the voltage levels that I linked for the logic low & high thresholds apply; (b) it may also refer to the actual fabrication technology used. || It is possible to have TTL-compatible voltage levels with non-TTL fabrication technology e.g. the 74HC**T** series of ICs (and actually many modern CMOS ICs). || "*Without a converter to 5V, it doesn't work*" Then some part(s) of your system is/are *not* using TTL-compatible logic levels. You are getting good answers. If it was me, I would research Tx & Rx devices more.

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson! Out of curiosity why do we call this trigger signal a TTL? Is it for Transistor Transistor Logic?

Comment: (a) Personally I think adding that image into your question may cause confusion, because as I said, if your devices were using those TTL logic level threshold voltages, then you would not have a problem! Therefore that image *should*, but *does not*, apply to your system. (b) "*why do we call this trigger signal a TTL?*" It *should* mean that TTL-compatible logic levels apply. But your symptoms mean that Tx, Rx or both devices are *not* using TTL-compatible logic levels. Personally I would investigate that contradiction further, but using one of the answers might be enough for you.

Comment: @SamGibson I edited my question and mentioned that this is the TTL standard (for future reference), but that probably my Rx Tx devices don't fully support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll mention a couple of solutions, though there are many. The first uses a single IC, a [74HCT1G08](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G08.pdf), or similar. Note the T in HCT; that's what enables it to be powered from 5V, to produce a 5V digital output, but also works with TTL-level inputs, where 2.4V is considered "high". This solution is very high speed, producing a very fast response and output transition.

The second uses A MOSFET to translate the level without inverting. It's slower, working up to 500kHz or so, but cheaper, and just as simple, really:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffyZiX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit on the right is available as pre-built module from [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) and [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009), both having four such translators on a single board, but given its simplicity, it seems silly not to DIY.

---

#### Update

I forgot to address the big question, the switching "threshold" of the MOSFET solution. It's not so much a threshold, as an input potential where the output suddenly rises to +5V, the point at which the MOSFET switches *off*. Below this point the MOSFET is on, and \$V_{OUT} = V_{IN}\$.

The threshold depends on \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ for the device, which for the  device shown, the [2N7000](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nds7002a-d.pdf), is \$V_{GS(TH)}=2.1V\$, typically (but could be up to 3V). Devices with lower \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ exist, such as the [BSS138](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bss138-d.pdf), having \$V_{GS(ON)}=+1.3V\$.

The threshold is approximately \$V_{IN(TH)}=+3.3V - V_{GS(TH)}\$, meaning that as shown, the sudden rise to \$V_{OUT}=+5V\$ happens at \$V_{IN}=+3.3V-2.1V=+1.2V\$. Below this input potential, \$V_{OUT}=V_{IN}\$:

[image]

Comment: The switching threshold for the left circuit is nicely documented in the AND gate datasheet.  What's the switching threshold for the right circuit?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, that's an oversight in my answer. I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Is there an off-the-self electronic solution to convert a 0 / 3.3 trigger into a 0 / 5 trigger signal ?

Yes, it is called a [level shifter](https://www.adafruit.com/product/395) and is commonly used for sending data between logic circuits operating at different voltages.

Comment: And that has got to be the most unsuitable level shifter for the job - it will work but only when the chip is placed in an extremely controlled environment, which the BNC cabling will surely fail to fulfill the chip requirements about load capacitance and signal flight of time.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there an off-the-self electronic solution to convert a 0 / 3.3
> trigger into a 0 / 5 trigger signal ?*

Quite a few CMOS buffers that run from a supply of 5 volts (and therefore produce a 5 volt logic high output) have inputs that are compatible with TTL levels. It's just a case of investigating which buffers are and are not TTL input compatible.

Answer (score 0):

First most "0-5V" inputs will work at 0 to 3.3V levels.  Check that first.
A SN74LXC1T level translator is designed to do this job.
Use a cell phone charger to power the IC.  5V to Vcco pin.  (add capacitor to ground)
Use two small diodes to drop the voltage to close to 3.3V for Vcci (add cap to gnd)
It will work if Vcci and Vcco are both at 5V because the input sees a 0 as and voltage below 1/2 supply and a 1 at any voltage above Vcci/2.  So 5V supply (Vcci) = 2.5V switching voltage.
[data sheet here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lxc1t14-q1.pdf)

[image]
It would help to know how fast a signal and what are you driving on the output.